# How to read a function parameter in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, buttonclick

I would like to delete a comment via Ajax in background, without refreshing a page.

I made a button with `onclick function` which will pass the id of the comment:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="return delete_comment(<?=$data['comment_id']; ?>);">Delete comment</button>
```

and I am not sure how to pass a comment id to PHP function:

```
<script>
function delete_comment(comment_id)
{
    if (confirm("Delete?")) {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/comments/delete/' + comment_id,
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
             alert("Deleted.");
          }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

To delete a comment I need to call PHP script like: `/comments/delete/comment_id`

Comment: Simply use `$_POST`  on your php file.

Comment: use  type: 'POST', nor  type: 'post',

Comment: What is the problem you are facing

Comment: What's the problem? We assume your code is not working, but what is happening? What does the console say, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming, the mistake you are making is, the type. If you use **`GET`** type. Then we can post the Javscript paramter to the PHP form using the page `/comments/delete/123123`.

But,since you are using **`POST`**. Specificing the comment id in the URL is not going to pass the variable into the PHP form. For which, you will have to use the following ajax.

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/comments/delete/',
     data: {
         id: comment_id
     },
     success: function () {
         alert("Deleted.");
     }
 });
```

**Method 2**

If you are not particular about the **`POST`** method. Then, you can change your PHP form to **`GET`** and the ajax type to **`GET`**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/comments/delete/' + comment_id,
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function () {
        alert("Deleted.");
    }
});
```

Comment: BTW: In Method 1, is it possible to pass with this method more than one parameter to the PHP, or Array/JSON need to be used?

Comment: Yes you can. use this `data` instead. data: {
         id: comment_id,
         param2 : "blahblah"
     },

Answer (score 0):

Thank all you guys for help.
The problem seems to be a PHP script not the mentioned HTML with Ajax

Comment: Yes, clearly. As i suggested in the my answer below, it was the problem with the form type. But I guess you didnt even have a look.